# Accessing static fields from the decorated class

Tags: python, class, class-decorator

Full code example:

```
def decorator(class_):
    class Wrapper:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.instance = class_(*args, **kwargs)

        @classmethod
        def __getattr__(cls, attr):
            return getattr(class_, attr)
    return Wrapper


@decorator
class ClassTest:

    static_var = "some value"


class TestSomething:

    def test_decorator(self):
        print(ClassTest.static_var)
        assert True
```

When trying to execute test, getting error:

```
test/test_Framework.py F
test/test_Framework.py:37 (TestSomething.test_decorator)
self = <test_Framework.TestSomething object at 0x10ce3ceb8>

    def test_decorator(self):
>       print(ClassTest.static_var)
E       AttributeError: type object 'Wrapper' has no attribute 'static_var'
```

Is it possible to access static fields from the decorated class?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting error? It is not immediately obvious from the code snippets above where the problem is.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided all the code which causes the error in a single snippet. It took me several minutes to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting a comment so that you can format the code properly.

Comment: Posted full code.

Comment: The `TestSomething` class is not necessary for this question, so I removed it.

Comment: `__getattr__` should not be used in class context. The issue is obvious. The `Wrapper` is not derived from `ClassTest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the answer from @martineau probably better addresses the specific issue you are trying to solve, the more general approach might be to use create a metaclass in order to redefine the *instance* method `__getattr__` on a `type` instance (and classes are instances of `type`).

```
def decorator(class_):
    class WrapperMeta(type):
        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            return getattr(class_, attr)

    class Wrapper(metaclass=WrapperMeta):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.instance = class_(*args, **kwargs)

    return Wrapper
```

This allows the attribute look-up on the class itself to be passed through `WrapperMeta.__getattr__`.

Comment: @Oleh Kuzovkov: IMO this answer is better than mine—so you should accept it. Jared: Meta interesting!

Comment: The main purpose of this question was to bypass fields calls to the decorated class. Inheritance solved the problem for sure, however this solution is really more suitable for this case. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to work by making the decorator create a class *derived* from the one being decorated.

Here's what I mean:

```
def decorator(class_):
    class Wrapper(class_):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.instance = super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    return Wrapper

@decorator
class ClassTest:
    static_var = "some value"

print(ClassTest.static_var)  # -> some value
```

Comment: Can you explain why the original code doesn't work? As a python newbie, I am unfamiliar with the `__getattr__()` method. Why does it not work like the OP expects it to?

Comment: A class doesn't have this method `__getattr__()`, that's all.  You could use `getattr(class_, name)` instead, that works I think.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Because the `__getattr__()` defined in the OP's code is a `Wrapper` classmethod. You can learn more about `__getattr__()` by reading its online [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

Comment: @martineau - In order to avoid inheriting from class_ - Can this be done with metaclass to override the Wrapper __getattr__ (some MetaWrapper)?

Comment: After decoration, the name `ClassTest` refers to the class `Wrapper`, correct? So shouldn't `Classtest.static_var` call `__getattr__()` in `Wrapper`?

Comment: @UriHoenig: A metaclass might be able to avoid inheriting from `class_` by copying all its static attributes into its class instances. Try it and see.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: The `__getattr__()` in the OP's `Wrapper` class isn't called when `ClassTest.static_var` is referenced. `__getattr__()` is for customizing the attribute access of class _instances_, so it only applies to them, not to **class** attributes (so it's unclear what making it a `@classmethod` would even mean).